# Durood Sharif and finality of prophethood

Tags: prophet-muhammad

Asa

Does the durood Sharif contain proof that Prophet Muhammad saw is not in fact the last and final messenger of Allah? 
What blessing must be just like Abraham?
What prosperous future must be just like Abraham?

Comment: Post more information, add quotes so that we may understand what you mean or refer to. As is written I doubt whether this actually makes sense to somebody else at all (at least not to me). To make it clear What is "durood Sharif" (full wording) -> full quote. And based on that ask your questions by quoting the parts that "distrub" you or you want "clarfication" about.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't and anyone who claims such a thing is professing to have greater insight than the Prophet himself, and hence can be safely ignored. Because the hadith are very straightforward on this issue:

> أَنَا خَاتَمُ النَّبِيِّينَ لاَ نَبِيَّ بَعْدِي
>
> I am the last of the Prophets, there will be no Prophet after me.

https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/33/62

> كَانَتْ بَنُو إِسْرَائِيلَ تَسُوسُهُمُ الأَنْبِيَاءُ كُلَّمَا هَلَكَ
>   نَبِيٌّ خَلَفَهُ نَبِيٌّ وَإِنَّهُ لاَ نَبِيَّ بَعْدِي
>
> The Israelis used to be ruled and guided by prophets: Whenever a
>   prophet died, another would take over his place. There will be no
>   prophet after me,

https://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/122

> ‏ أَمَا تَرْضَى أَنْ تَكُونَ مِنِّي بِمَنْزِلَةِ هَارُونَ مِنْ مُوسَى
>   غَيْرَ أَنَّهُ لاَ نَبِيَّ بَعْدِي
>
> Aren't you satisfied with being unto me what Aaron was unto Moses but
>   with this exception that there would be no prophet after me?

https://sunnah.com/muslim/44/48